# Oracle is not working with Japanese OS issue

Tags: windows, oracle

I have a query which returns second and fourth saturdays of given year,

```
WITH ALL_SATURDAYS AS
  (SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01012014','DDMMYYYY'),'WW')                              * (level)                                                                                       AS WEEK_NO,
    NEXT_DAY(TO_DATE('01012014','DDMMYYYY')                                         + (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01012014','DDMMYYYY'),'WW' ) * (level-1) * 7),'土')                        AS SATURDAY_DATE,
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY TO_CHAR(NEXT_DAY(TO_DATE('01012014','DDMMYYYY') + (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01012014','DDMMYYYY'),'WW' ) * (level-1) * 7),'土'),'月') ORDER BY level) AS Pos
  FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY level<= 52
  ORDER BY 1
  )
SELECT SATURDAY_DATE,POS FROM ALL_SATURDAYS WHERE POS IN (2,4) ORDER BY 1,2
```

It's working in other systems, but mine is a japanese os when i execute this query it returns `ORA-01821: date format not recognized` error.

How can i fix the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `月` with `MONTH`.  The Datetime Format Elements are always in English, even though the results may be in another language.

```
alter session set nls_date_language=japanese;
select to_char(date '2014-01-01', 'MONTH') month from dual;

Month
-----
1月
```